# How to take XPath of element that is between br tags with <strong> in account

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, tags

My code is like this,

```
<div>
    <strong> Text1: </strong>
    1234
    <br>
    <strong> Text2: </strong>
    5678
    <br>
</div>
```

where numbers, 1234 and 5678 are generated dynamically. When I take XPath of Text2 : 5678, it gives me like /html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/br[2]. This does not work for me. I need to take XPath of only "Text2 : 5678". any help will be appreciated. (I am using selenium webdriver and C# to code my test script)

Comment: <br> tag does not have a content in the above snippet. So this won't be able to locate any text from your xpath.
And the numeric value does come under the div instead of br.So, to get the text using xpath, you need to get the div data and get your required data by coding.

Comment: I am new to this, so can can you please suggest me something. Would solution similar to //br/preceding-sibling::*/text() would help?

Comment: @prabh: your solution will give error if you execute it.

Comment: by using x-path , you won't be able to locate the numeric values as the comes under  div.
So, just tell me, do you have only these two text values in you div.
or, the number of these numeric values can change(example, for now, I can see 2 numeric values "1234" and "5678". will this data will have 2 numeric values all time)

Comment: @Anil Chandna: numeric value changes every time, and i need to use numeric value that is after Text 2 i.e. 5678 which will be new each time

Answer (score 1):

I second @Anil's comment above. The text **"Text2:"** is retrievable as it is within **"strong"**  element. But, **"5678"** comes under **div** and is not the innerHTML for either **"strong" or "br"**.

Hence, to retrieve the text **"Text 2: 5678"**, you'll have to retrieve the innerHTML/text of **"div"** and modify it accordingly to get the required text.

**Below is a Java code snippet to retrieve the text:-**

```
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div"));

    System.out.print(ele.getText().split("\n")[1]; //Splitting using newline as the split string.
```

I hope you can formulate the above in **C#**.